# STM32 - Help with I2C slave device - variable length master message

Tags: stm32, i2c

I want to implement an I2C slave with a STM32L476 microcontroller that basically behaves like a memory. Therefore it must respond to another microcontroller which executes the `HAL_I2C_Mem_Write()` and `HAL_I2C_Mem_Read()` operations to this slave.

Searching on the internet I came to write this code and it seems to work.

```c
void HAL_I2C_SlaveRxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c) {
    printf("--> DEBUG: Write [%02X - %02X - %02X]\r\n", i2c_rx_buffer[0],
            i2c_rx_buffer[1], i2c_rx_buffer[2]);
}
 
void HAL_I2C_AddrCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint8_t TransferDirection, uint16_t AddrMatchCode) {
    if (TransferDirection == 0) {
        memset(i2c_rx_buffer, 0x00, MAX_I2C_RX_LEN);
        if (HAL_I2C_Slave_Seq_Receive_IT(EXT_I2C, i2c_rx_buffer, MAX_I2C_RX_LEN, I2C_FIRST_AND_LAST_FRAME) != HAL_OK) {
            Error_Handler();
        }
    } else {
        printf("--> Read \r\n");
        i2c_tx_buffer[0] = 0xFF;
        if (HAL_I2C_Slave_Seq_Transmit_IT(EXT_I2C, i2c_tx_buffer, MAX_I2C_RX_LEN, I2C_FIRST_AND_LAST_FRAME) != HAL_OK) {
            Error_Handler();
        }
    }
}
 
void HAL_I2C_ListenCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c) {
    if(HAL_I2C_EnableListen_IT(EXT_I2C) != HAL_OK) {
          printf("********************** ERROR START LISTEN I2C\r\n");
          Error_Handler();
      }
}
 
void HAL_I2C_ErrorCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c) {
    printf("HAL_I2C_ErrorCallback\r\n");
}
```

But now I have a problem:
How do I deal with the fact that I don't know how many bytes will be written?
Since I don't know how long the packet that the master sends will be, what number should I put in the `HAL_I2C_Slave_Seq_Receive_IT` function? I tried to make a very large buffer, but if the master sends a variable number of bytes, the `HAL_I2C_ErrorCallback` is always called.
How can I handle receiving a variable number of bytes?

Comment: So you can't determine in the error callback how many bytes you received?

Comment: Yes, maybe there could be a way to figure out how many bytes were received in the Error Callback,but is it a good idea to use an Error Callback for normal operation?
Isn't there a cleaner and more elegant solution?

Comment: You can use any method available that allows you to implement something you want to implement.

Comment: OK, and do you know how I could go about knowing how many bytes were received in the error callback?

Comment: From the i2c handle struct members?